# Obtain part of a string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, substring

I am trying to pull out part of a string in Oracle SQL developer. The same number of characters are at the start and I want to cut off the end which begins "at"
Example:

Row 1 `Assigned to Bob Smith at the examiner level`.

Row 2 `Assigned to Jane Doe at the corporate level`.

Want to return "`Bob Smith`" and "`Jane Doe`"

I have tried using `regex_substr` but I am confused as to the application of each part.

Comment: It would be useful if you tell us what programming language you're using.

Comment: Sorry, my first post

Comment: @user6000266 lol, thats a pretty good one (forgetting to write what language). Anyways, welcome to SO!

Comment: add a language tag to the list of tags, the tags you have now are USELESS, also **edit your questions** and **show what you have tried** in all questions, otherwise they look like *give me teh codez* demands.

Comment: If all the names start at the same position, use `SUBSTR` first to cut off the beginning text and then use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to take only the name. Providing all the names are 2 words, otherwise you're SOL.

Comment: I have no excuse, I just hope my coding isn't so sloppy. Cheers

Comment: I used the substr function but I do not understand how to cut out the end after the name

Comment: @user6000266 You need to use both SUBSTR and INSTR. INSTR is to avoid hard-coding the position. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using:

- **SUBSTR**
- **INSTR**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'Assigned to Bob Smith at the examiner level' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Assigned to Jane Doe at the corporate level' str FROM dual
  4  )
  5  -- end of smaple_data mimicking real table
  6  SELECT rtrim(SUBSTR(str,
  7                      instr(str, 'Assigned to ', 1, 1) + LENGTH('Assigned to '),
  8                      instr(str, ' at the ', 1, 1)    - LENGTH('Assigned to ')),
  9               ' ') sub_str
 10  FROM sample_data;

SUB_STR
-------------------------------------------
Bob Smith
Jane Doe

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't said which language you're using.

Assuming it's Javascript you can get all names from the original string, say `text`:

```
var names = text.match(/Row \d+ Assigned to ([\w\s]+?) at the .+ level/);
```

To be transposed into any convenient language if needed.